# How to take only required thing from UNIX time-stamp in jquery?

Tags: jquery, unix, timestamp, date-format, unix-timestamp

I have UNIX time-stamp (1397376075),

```
var date = new Date((1397376075)*1000);
```

When I print `date` by above code it give me something like this:-

```
Sun Apr 13 2014 01:01:15 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
```

but I want only :-

`Sun Apr 13 2014 01:01:15`

what should i do for this to get only above data

Answer (score 1):

There are several built-in JavaScript functions for getting specific pieces of a Date object. See the reference on W3Schools: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp